# wp-cli eval over ssh - "Too many positional arguments"

Tags: wordpress, ssh, wp-cli

Using WP-CLI's `eval` over SSH and getting an error on the simplest of commands:

```
wp eval "echo WP_CONTENT_DIR;" --ssh=forge@mysite.com
Error: Too many positional arguments: WP_CONTENT_DIR
```

I can SSH in and run commands myself just fine. Anyone have an idea of what's going on? I can very easily

Comment: How is wp defined? The error message appears to come from the script for wp.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does. wp is an alias for [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/).

Comment: Try bypassing wp by invoking the phar file directly, e.g. php wp-cli\php\boot-phar.php eval "echo WP_CONTENT_DIR;"